# Retrieving values from URL in HTTP Post

Tags: html, asp.net, http-post

I am struggling to get values out of a url so I can use them in ASP.Net core. The url will look something like this:

`/ResetPassword?id=17&token=a1f5995d-54ab-48a4-adef-4c914b58aed2`

I can get the Id and the Token in the first instance in a method like so:

```
[Route("resetpassword")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ResetPassword(int id, string token)
{
    if (await _profileService.VerifyUser(id, token))
    {
        return View(new ResetPasswordViewModel { Id = id, Token = token });
    }
    return View(new ResetPasswordViewModel { ErrorCode = 1 });
}
```

As you can see I do a check to make sure I can verify the User. This then takes the user to another screen where they fill in a couple of inputs and hit a submit button. I am using HTTP post for this so I can get the User's input however I cannot workout how to retrieve the Id and Token again. This is what the form looks like:

```
       <form method="post" asp-controller="Profile" asp-action="ResetPassword"
              asp-route-returnUrl="@Context.Request.Query["returnUrl"]">
            <img class="card-img-top user-image" src="~/images/user.svg" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" asp-for="Password" placeholder="New Password" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" asp-for="ConfirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="button" style="width: 100%;">Reset Password</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

and then this is the HTTP Post action:

```
[Route("resetpassword")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> ResetPassword(int id, string token, 
                                               string password, string confirmPassword)
{
    if (await _profileService.VerifyUser(id, token))
    {
        //Do something with passwords
    }
    return View(new ResetPasswordViewModel { ErrorCode = 1 });
}
```

So the passwords that are posted to this method I am able to retrieve but I am unable to then use the Id and Token to validate the User again. I have tried storing them locally in the controller but this did not work.

Do I need to have two hidden inputs that store those values that can then be submitted in the form? I thought there would be a cleaner solution to what I wanted to achieve so I am posting this question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `TempData`;

```
if (await _profileService.VerifyUser(id, token))
{
    TempData["ResetPassword_id"] = id;
    TempData["ResetPassword_token"] = token;
    return View(new ResetPasswordViewModel { Id = id, Token = token });
}
```

And then get the `id` and `token`;

```
[Route("resetpassword")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> ResetPassword(int id, string token,
    string password, string confirmPassword)
{
    var id = (int)TempData["ResetPassword_id"];
    var token = (string)TempData["ResetPassword_token"];
    if (await _profileService.VerifyUser(id, token))
    {
        //Do something with passwords
    }
    return View(new ResetPasswordViewModel { ErrorCode = 1 });
}
```